# Need assistance with an sql query that sorts image gallery based on user choice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting, gallery

For my website I have an image gallery and I want the user to be able to sort the gallery by title asc, title desc and by emotion. This website is for people with dementia so I am recording positive or negative emotional reactions from an image.

I have the title asc and desc queries working but am struggling with the final query to sort by emotion.

My database has the following setup:

1. images : id, title, ...etc      //stores the image and properties
2. imageaccess : imageID, userID    //stores who has access to view image
3. imageemotion : imageID, userID, happyCount, sadCount    //stores emotions elicited by image

So far this is the query I have come up with but it does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM imageaccess WHERE imageaccess.imageID=images.id AND imageaccess.userID='$currentUserID') FULL OUTTER JOIN imageemotions ON imageemotions.imageID=images.id ORDER BY imageemotions.happyCount DESC
```

Basically I need a query that will return all images that the user has access to and sort the result by 'happyCount'.
Currently an image will only be added to the 'imageemotion' table when a happyCount or sadCount is registered by the user, however if it will make the query easier I could update the website so that every image will contain a happy and sad count of 0.

Really hope this makes sense I know it is rather complicated...any help will be much appreciated!

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    images.*,
    IFNULL(imageemotions.happyCount, 0) AS happyCount, 
    IFNULL(imageemotions.sadCount, 0) AS sadCount
FROM 
    images 
    INNER JOIN imageaccess 
        ON imageaccess.imageID = images.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN imageemotions 
        ON imageemotions.imageID = images.id 
WHERE 
    imageaccess.userID = '$currentUserID'
ORDER BY 
    IFNULL(imageemotions.happyCount, 0) DESC
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much it was doing my head in :)

Comment: I'm really glad I could help :)